# jquery slider seiyera shows text box only

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-slider

I am having an issue when trying to implement `seiyria-slider`.

Here's my code:

```js
 // Here's the initialization:

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ex2").slider({});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
     <label for="">Confidence Score</label> 
     <div class="slider-holder"> 
         <input id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="[0,100]"/>
     </div>
</div>

<!-- Also links to css and js files placed at bottom of file: -->

<link href="{{ url('js/components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ url('js/components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But only a text box is displayed instead of slider.

[image]

Comment: if you look into the browser dev tools under network tab, are all scripts also loaded correctly? Maybe you get a 404 or so somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It is found that the issue was due to `jquery-ui` included.

Removing those solved the issue.